# how to do a function using an array of chars in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, void

the problem is that i dont know how to send char[x][x] to the void i know how to make them but not how to pass them.

```
void thefunction(????????????????)
{ 
    for(int i;i<20;i++)
    { 
        cin>>thearray[x-1]; 
    } 
} 
int main()
{ 
    char thearray[21][20];
    thefunction(?????????????); 
}
```

i serously tried most of the youtube tutorials but no one did this on specific i seriously dont know how to send the array to the function

```
voidname(arrayname[f],20);
void voidname(char arrayname,int [],int [])
{
}
```

and many other ways that tutorials on youtube try

Comment: yes i have to use char because of my univeristy teacher is old and he hates strings he said that no strings allowed so i have to do it with char

Comment: What does "connect them" mean? Concatenate? If so, you're stuck using `strcat` etc.

Comment: as conect them i mean how do i fill the ?????? parts he taught us is called conect but i dont know if conect is the right translation from spanish to english

Comment: How would you write the code if you were passing a 1D array? Start there. A 2 D array is nothing but an an array of arrays., so if you can get 1 D figured out you're most of the way to 2D.

Comment: Here's some really helpful reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8767247/4581301 Example 1 is almost exactly what you need.

Comment: @ferminsalaberry -- Are you allowed to use `struct`?  If so, then you could wrap the 2D array in a struct, and pass the struct.  Then the array is neatly packed into the struct you passed.

Comment: `void thefunction(char thearray[21][20])` . The C language was designed so the parameter declaration can match the argument declaration.  Generally regarded as a mistake now by many

Comment: @ferminsalaberry -- See the answer from user4581301 to show how to use the struct.  That to me is the simplest way of doing this, as you avoid pointers, and everything just works, without a lot of changes.  Your professor cannot complain you are using strings, since you are still using the 2D char array, only in a different manner.

Comment: @ferminsalaberry Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to search and then research and you'll find plenty of related SO posts for this.

Comment: @ferminsalaberry **C++ must be learnt using a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of by watching youtube tutorials.**

Comment: [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is your friend. Forget that C-style arrays exist in the language.

Answer (score 2):

To pass a 1D array we would

```cpp
void function(char arr[])
{
    // do stuff to arr
}

char arr[20];
function(arr);
```

Note the absence of the size in `function`'s parameter `arr[]`. This causes problems because `arr` [has decayed to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay) no longer knows how big it is. You almost always have to

```cpp
void function(char arr[], 
              size_t len) // so function knows when to stop putting stuff into arr
{
    // do stuff to arr
}
```

A 2D array is an array of arrays, so the function needs to look like it's getting a pointer to an array of the size of the inner dimension

```cpp
void function(char arr[][some_size_here], 
              size_t len) // so function knows how big arr's outer dimension is
{
    // do stuff to arr
}
```

In this case `some_size_here` is 20.

```cpp
void function(char arr[][20], 
              size_t len) // so function knows how big arr's outer dimension is
{
    // do stuff to arr
}
```

This is probably where your instructor expects you to stop. But why?

We can get sneakier and generalize the function with a template so you don't always have to pass in a 20 character inner array:

```cpp
template <size_t N>
void function(char arr[][N], 
              size_t len) // so function knows how big arr's outer dimension is
{
    // do stuff to arr
}
```

But if we're going to do that, we can go in all the way and template everything:

```cpp
template <size_t M, size_t N>
void function(char (&arr)[M][N]) 
{
    // do stuff to arr
}
```

This no longer needs the extra `len` parameter because it knows the lengths, `M` and `N`. There is the odd wrinkle though. Since the array would decay to a pointer, you need to pass the array by reference to preserve its array-ness from decaying and collect the size of the first dimension. Or at least that's why I think you have to do it. There could be some other screwball reason that I never figured out.

Side note: This is a really good trick for determining the size of an array without using the `sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])` trick. The template captures the size for you and you just return it. See [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) to see this trick in action. This is safer than `sizeof` because `sizeof` will accept a pointer from a decayed array and provide the size of the pointer divided by the size of the first element, which is almost always wrong. The template trick will not compile if you accidentally feed in a pointer, saving you much debugging.

We can also make a structure that contains the array and pass the structure around

```cpp
struct array
{
    char thearray[21][20];
}

void function(array & arr)
{
    // use arr.thearray
}
```

Here we want to pass by reference rather than by value (and this is about the only good way to pass an array without it decaying)  so we won't be operating on a copy. A great many new C++ programmers get confused the first few times they accidentally pass a value they need to edit into a function by value and find that back at the caller the original value went unchanged.

Add templating to generalize the size and a few helpful operator overloads onto the array-in-a-`struct` trick and you've pretty much just reinvented [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

A quick note about `cin>>thearray[x-1];`: It is only recently that `>>` reading into a character array became a thing and prevented buffer buffer overflow. Traditionally because the array had decayed to a pointer and the length was lost, `>>` would gleefully write past the end of the array and wreck havoc on the program. If your compiler is out of date, this can be one hell of a boobytrap. This is one of the many reasons `std::string` comes highly recommended.

Comment: For the `struct` example, I would show how to get to the internal array using `.`.  I know it sounds trivial, but just for completeness.

Comment: Solid point, @Paul . How is that?

Comment: Gets an upvote.

Comment: Using `cin >>` directly to a char array is _safe_ (only stores up to array size-1 characters) [since C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2), but before that was a _fire hazard_.

Answer (score 0):

> how to do a function using an array of chars in c++
>
> ```
> char thearray[21][20];
> ```

`thearray` is not an array of chars. It is an array of arrays of char.

A typical way to pass an array into a function is to use the `std::span` template. Since the elements of the array in this case are arrays of 20 chars, you would use `std::span<char[20]>`. Example:

```
#include <span>

void thefunction(std::span<char[20]> arrays) { 
    for (auto& array : arrays) { 
        std::cin >> array;
    } 
} 

// usage
char thearray[21][20];
thefunction(thearray);
```